# vue doesn't update the child chart component in echart

Tags: vue.js, echarts

I have built a vue component to show a PIE chart in echart library as showed below. The PIE chart will be initialized with a default value.

pieChart.vue

```
<template>
  <div :class="className" :style="{height:height,width:width}" />
</template>

<script>
import echarts from 'echarts'
require('echarts/theme/macarons') // echarts theme
import resize from './mixins/resize'
export default {
  mixins: [resize],
  props: {
    className: {
      type: String,
      default: 'chart'
    },
    width: {
      type: String,
      default: '100%'
    },
    height: {
      type: String,
      default: '300px'
    },
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }    
  },
  watch: {
    chartData: function(val){
        console.log('chartdata handler',val);
        this.setOptions(val.legend, val.data);
    }
  },  
  data() {
    return {
      chart: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.initChart()
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (!this.chart) {
      return
    }
    this.chart.dispose()
    this.chart = null
  },
  methods: {
    initChart() {
      this.chart = echarts.init(this.$el, 'macarons');
      this.setOptions(
         ['group_a','group_b','group_c'],
         [
           { value: 1, name: 'group_a' },
           { value: 2, name: 'group_b' },
           { value: 3, name: 'group_c' },
        ]
      );
    },

    setOptions( lengend, data ) {

      this.chart.setOption({
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'item',
          formatter: '{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)'
        },
        legend: {
          left: 'center',
          bottom: '10',
          data: lengend
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'WEEKLY WRITE ARTICLES',
            type: 'pie',
            roseType: 'radius',
            radius: '50%',
            data: data,
            animationEasing: 'cubicInOut',
            animationDuration: 2600
          }
        ]
      });

    }

  }
}
</script>
```

then I use this component in a view.

```
<template>
    <pie-chart :chartData="updateData"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
        name: 'Personalinforadm',
        components: { 
            PieChart,
        },
        data() {
            return {
             updateData: {
               data:[
                  { value: 33, name: 'group_a' },
                  { value: 17, name: 'group_b' },
                  { value: 3, name: 'group_c' },
              ],
              legend:['group_a','group_b','group_c']
             }
         }
      },
        created() {

            this.updateData = {
               data:[
                  { value: 3, name: 'group_a' },
                  { value: 17, name: 'group_b' },
                  { value: 3, name: 'group_c' },
              ],
              legend:['group_a','group_b','group_c']
             }
        }
}
</script>
```

however the view doesn't update the PIE chart component with the new values in created methods. why the new values doesn't pass to the PIE component and trigger the watch methods, any ideas what goes wrong with the code?

Comment: Does the console.log in your watcher get triggered?

Comment: no, I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts or solution below may help you.(if you use version >4.x)

sample.vue

```
<template>
   //...
   <v-chart
     class="chart mt-7"
     :option="botChartData"
     :update-options="updateOpts"
   />
   //...
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            updateOpts: {
               notMerge: true,
            },
            botChartData: {
                 tooltip: {
                      trigger: "item",
                      formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)",
                 },
                 series: [
                  {
                    name: "Active Bots",
                    type: "pie",
                    center: ["50%", "50%"],
                    radius: ["75%", "90%"],
                    itemStyle: {
                      borderRadius: 8,
                    },
                    data: [],
                   }
                 ],
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
       connect() {
         this.bots = [
           {
              value: 0,
              name: "a",
           },
           {
              value: 1,
              name: "b",
           },
           {
              value: 2,
              name: "c",
           },
         ];
         this.botChartData.series[0].data = this.bots;
       }
    },
};
</script>
```

I called "connect" in "created" you can call it in mounted or on events!

if you need to set your chart as a child component you can easily pass **this.botChartData** like below

child.vue

```
<template>
  <v-chart
     class="chart mt-7"
     :option="botData"
     :update-options="updateConf"
  />
 </template>

 <script>
  export default {
     props: {
        botChartData: {
             type: Object
        },
        updateOpts: {
             type: Object
        }
     },
     computed: {
        botData() {
           return this.botChartData
        },
        updateConf() {
           return this.updateOpts
        }
     }
  };
 </script>
```

in parent.vue

```
<template>
 //...
 <sample :botChartData="botChartData" :updateOpts="updateOpts" />
 //...
</template>
<script>
  //...the same as sample.vue js
</script>
```

By the way if you have multiple charts in one page **dont forget notMerge** then your charts will reinitialize after switching between them